# Is it safe to abort a CHECK TABLE (mysql) query? (check table TBL_NAME fast)

Tags: mysql, linux, crash

Is it safe to abort a CHECK TABLE (mysql) query? (check table TBL_NAME fast)

Or can this have impact on the data? Corruption? The table has GBs of data and the server crashed so, now its checking, and its taking a long time.

So if the table is in good state, and you run this query, and abort it, can it cause corruption?

(I have 6GB ram, and the data is maybe 4gb, so i will run the query later again, maybe some tips for the mysql configuration to make this query faster? something with cache?)

Answer (score -1):

u can use

```
check table your_table fast quick;
```

mysql [check table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question though. Will aborting corrupt data?

Comment: this doesn't answer the users question